# Добавить вывод уведомления каждые 3 минуты

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста как в `eclipse`, в проекте под `Android. Добавить вывод уведомления **каждые 3 минуты**.

Или без кнопки, что бы при запуске оно просто выводилось каждые 3 минуты.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду уведомления при работе приложения Android?

Comment: Да, например, какое-то приложение запущено, например, часы цифровые и аналоговые. И поверх появлялось уведомление каждые 3 минуты, например, с новым годом.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать это при помощи AlarmManager:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SomeApp.this, someService.class);     
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

pi = PendingIntent.getService(SomeApp.this, 0, i, 0);

// Выбираем время начала - полночь
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

// Делаем повтор на каждые три минуты
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 3*60*1000, pi);
```

Comment: А уведомление в таком виде?

Context context = getApplicationContext();

        CharSequence text = "С новым годом!";

        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

        toast.show();

Answer (score 1):

а можно по старинке, сделать таймер и выводить каждые 3 минуты тост

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener(
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
Toast.makeText(this, "С новым годом!",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
));
timer.start();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так и в правду короче)

Comment: немного поправил.. как по мне мой способ легче, но если мы все же говорим про андроид, я бы склонялся к варианту - разобраться с AlarmManager и сделать вывод, когда его использовать лучше

Comment: Попробую, оба варианта.

Comment: У меня возникла проблема Eclipse ругается на скобки и на timer.start();, или я вообще неправельно сделал.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;

public class QActivity extends Activity {
 
 Timer timer = new Timer(3000,
 ActionListener = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "С новым годом!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
       }
   ));
  
  timer.start();  
       
       }
 }

Comment: extends Activity {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Timer timer = new Timer(3000,
        ActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        .... 

ты должен как и везде переопределить метод onCreate(), ну и правильно по закрывать скобки

Comment: Вы не могли бы выслать полный листинг программы по почте? Что то у меня всёравно не получается(((  dayverstorm@mail.ru